# Laravel 5.5: Dependency Injection on user model

Tags: laravel, repository-pattern

I have a BaseRepository class with methods which will be valid for all Models. The only problem is, that the User model is derived from use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User. So it throws me a type error because the constructor requires an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eleoquent\Model. How can I solve the problem?

Here is my UserRepository.php:

```
namespace App\Repositories\User;

use App\Model\User; use App\Repositories\Base\BaseRepository;

class UserRepository extends BaseRepository {

public function __construct(User $user)
{
 parent::__construct($user);
}

}
```

BaseRepository.php

```
namespace App\Repositories\Base;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eleoquent\Model;

class BaseRepository {

public function __construct (Model $model) {
    $this->model = $model;
}

public function all() {

    return $this->model->orderBy('id','desc')->get();


}


}
```

This is the error: Type error: 
**Argument 1 passed to App\Repositories\Base\BaseRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eleoquent\Model, instance of App\User given, called in C:\wamp64\www\adblog\app\Repositories\User\UserRepository.ph‌​p**

Comment: I think you could try with contextual binding. So when your `UserRepository` class needs a `User` you can pass the actual user instance.

Comment: Did you notive your typo? Does your base class constructor expect Illuminate\Database\Eleoquent\Model or Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model?

Comment: The User model is an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` ... ALL models you use are `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` that is what makes them an Eloquent Model, they extend Model.

Comment: anywho, the actual error would be nice ... not your version of what you think the error means

Comment: This is the error:

Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Repositories\Base\BaseRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eleoquent\Model, instance of App\User given, called in C:\wamp64\www\adblog\app\Repositories\User\UserRepository.php

Answer (score 2):

Customize your `User` model like this

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements
    AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
But this is the content from Illuminate\Foundation\Auth

Comment: Yep, just to make your User model extend Eloquent\Model and not Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User?

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem. User is of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as it extends this class.

Comment: "the constructor requires an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model", just what the OP says

Comment: Yes, but "Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable" inherits from the class "model"

Comment: @sammy That's what I mean. Maybe provide your base class constrcutor code and the exact error message.

Comment: See my post above. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No idea? I am wondering because this problem is not unusually think.